# Storing generated integers into an array to produce a string

Tags: c, string

I've seen a problem,  where it is told that there is a string which consists of numbers like  **"123456789101112131415...k"**,  where k is an input from user. **k** is the only input here.  The string is generated based on the input.  Suppose I enter 11. The string would be **"1234567891011"**.  It is told to generate the *k-th* element of string . 
For example,  for k=21,  output would be 5.

In C++,  I can actually create a string type array and store integers from a for loop into it via **to_string** function.  But,  I'm actually at a loss how to do it in C.  The only thing I know of scanning a string into an array is :

```
scanf(" %[^\n]", array);
```

**source:** : https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/1177/A

I'm new in C.  Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: Have you considered using `fgets()`? Watch out for the retained newline at the back end.

Comment: Not sure... But why do you need to *read* this string from input? Your only input as I understand is `k`. What you *might* want to use here is `sprintf`. But I would think of a better algorithmic solution

Comment: string[21] = '5'.

Comment: If you ony need the input for `int k` you can use `int ret = scanf("%d", &k);` in C.

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. Do you need to generate the _entire_ string of numbers - or just _change_ a single digit? Something else?

Comment: @Eugene I'm reading only k,  but I'm storing it into  an array. Later on,  I'm printing the k-th element...

Comment: @David only the k-th element

Comment: @NehalSamee: Where does the original string come from?

Comment: @NehalSamee: It's still not clear to me I'm afraid. Your definition of the required inputs, outputs and variables is ill-defined as far as I can discern.

Comment: @David added source..now?

Comment: @NehalSamee: This is really a question of algorithm design rather than a question specific to the C language or strings.

Have you tried solving the problem with a pen and paper? Knowledge of string manipulation in C is not needed for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equivalent of what you describe in C++, to C, is the following complete example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 1024

int main(void)
{
  int k;
  scanf("%d", &k);  // read input

  char str[SIZE] = {0};
  char generated_str[SIZE] = {0};

  for(int i = 1; i <= k; i++)
  {
    sprintf(str, "%d", i);        // convert int to string
    strcat(generated_str, str);   // append current term to the overall string
  }

  printf("%s\n", generated_str);
  printf("%c\n", generated_str[k - 1]);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
123456789101112131415161718192021
5
```

Note: Probably there is an algorithmic method to do that though.. Think about the number of digits every number has. Then think about of how you can use the modulo and the division operators (by 10) to get what you need from a number. After that, you should go and have fun.

Comment: Awesome...undersrood! Now,  what should I do in case of overflow?? @gsamaras

Comment: I tried the algorithm you mentioned.. It came to my mind readily...but it gives time limit exceeded for larger values like 21

Comment: I guess go algorithmic @NehalSamee! That was just a thought I had, I didn't really think that over... :) But that's another question. :)

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, this is more a question of algorithm design than C programming or string-handling. Perhaps the easiest way to approach it is to imagine the string as consisting of several 'blocks' of numbers.

- block 1 consists of the numbers 1 - 9 and starts at offset 0
- block 2 contains numbers 10 - 99 and starts at offset 9
- block 3 contains numbers 100 - 999 and starts at offset 189
- etc.

Because we know the offset of each block, we can compute the offset *within a block* that the global offset `k` corresponds to.

E.g., if `k = 207`, we know the relevant digit must begin in block 3 (number range `100` to `999`), and that its offset within this block is `207 - 189 = 8`. Since each number within this block has 3 digits, offset 8 must correspond to the third number in the block - i.e `102`. And since the remainder of 8 divided by 3 is 2, we know we are looking for the third digit in this number (indices begin at 0).

A picture would help to explain this - but it's late, so ...

In code ...

```c
static char find_kth_digit(int k) {
    int offset = 0;        // Global offset
    int block_length = 0;  // Length of current 'block'
    int offset_inner = 0;  // Offset within current block
    // Power to which 10 is currently raised
    int l = 1;
    int start = 1, end = 10;  // start / end of current block
    char digit = '0';         // result

    if (k == 0) { 
        return -1;
    }

    // Our indices start at 0 - while the question demands they begin at 1.
    k--;

    while (l < 5) {  // Only required to go up to k = 10000
        end = start * 10;
        offset_inner = k - offset;
        // How many digits overall in the current block of numbers?
        block_length = l * (end - start);
        // Update global offset
        offset = offset + block_length;
        // Is k within these block?
        if (k < offset) {
            int n = start + offset_inner / l;
            int d = offset_inner % l;
            return kth_digit_from_end_of_n(n, l - d);
        }
        l++;
        start = end;
    }

    if (l == 5) {
        return -1;
    }

    return digit;
}
```

A helper to find a particular digit within a number ...

```c
static char kth_digit_from_end_of_n(int n, int k) {
    char c = '0';
    while (k--) {
        c = n % 10;
        n /= 10;
    }
    return c + '0';
}
```

Note that - internally - the algorithm uses indices starting at 0, while the question you linked to expects indices starting at 1. Hence the need to decrement the offset before the main `while()` loop:

```c
k--;
```